# Categories Listing and Highlighting current category item

Tags: posts, categories, php, permalinks, array

My query is on Wordpress and related to categories.

I have a set of categories for my posts: All, Cat-a, Cat-b and Cat-c.

a. When I click on the link to my posts page, I want to show an archive for 'All'. How do I generate a link to 'All' explicitly? Something of this kind?

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">All Posts</a>
```

b. I would also be displaying the list of categories (shown below). I would however need to highlight the current category (by default, All).

```
<ul>
   <?php wp_list_categories('title_li='); ?>
</ul>
```

c. Also I would need all categories to be displayed whether they have posts in them or not.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an explicit category named "All", or do you just mean "all posts"?

Comment: I do have an explicit category called 'All', however that can be altered in the argument list in the wp_list_category() codex. When viewing a page of posts, I wanted the 'All' category highlighted, that's why I wanted to link to the dynamic link to the 'All' page. Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [the Codex page for `wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories), you can see the two following arguments that might help you:

- `hide_empty`: Toggles the display of categories with no posts. The default is `true` (hide empty categories).
- `current_category`: Allows you to force the `current-cat` CSS class to appear on uses of `wp_list_categories()` that are not on category archive pages.

Note that `current_category` only accepts *one* category ID. If you have a post that belongs to two categories, you will have to choose one.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer Jan! Greatly appreciated! Apologies for my delayed response, however, as I have one more query. Where do I specify which category to choose?

Comment: Ok, so the current_category is where I explicitly put in the ID of the category. However, that doesn't seem to activate the current-cat class in CSS. Also what I have done to get part of the intended result was this:

  <?php wp_list_categories('show_option_all=All&hide_empty=0&title_li='); ?>
I am unable to frame a condition that: if the page loaded is the archive of a particular category, then current-cat CSS class for that category should be activated. 

Any tips? Thanks!